# why hibernate query with relation trigger the father select?

Tags: hibernate, hql, many-to-one

I have a class "Father" with relation "oneToMany":

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "father")
Public class Father
{
   Private String id;
   Private Long a;
   Private Long b;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.Lazy, 
              mappedBy = 'father',
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   Private List<Son> son;
}
```

Class "Son" with relation "manyToOne":

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "son")
Public class Son
{
   Private String id;
   Private Father father;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   Public Father getFather(){
      return father;
   }

}
```

In my test I want to select for "father" and after select for "son",

to select "father" I need to use join from a few tables, after that I do an hql query

```java
 String sql = "select father.id, a.a, b.b"+
              "from father father join a a on father.id=a.id"+
              " join b b onb.id=a.id"+
              " where a.id="123";
 SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar(...);
 query.setParameter("id", "123");
 query.list();
 hql = "FROM SON WHERE ID =: id";
 Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
 query.setParameter("id", "123");
 query.list(); \\ actually hibernate run select from son and after select from father
```

hibernate did "select from son" and after that "select from father" **again**.

How I can tell hibernate I **already** have the father, so he doesn't select father itself?

Comment: Show the query in its entirety.. or all of that you need to use

Answer (score 1):

@ManyToOne is fetched EAGERly by default. You should add FetchType.Lazy to avoid the select.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
```